# WAMP mysql not working after server restart

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

server was after restart in the morning
wamp cannot start
Apache and php are running but mysql is not
the error in the log was about innodb. i did force the inno db and now the error is:

```
Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist
```

tried to install wamp on another machine and copy all /data folder but the on phpmyadmin i get `error 1146 Table 'xxx.xxxxx' doesn't exist` for each table i try to open

Answer (score -1):

try export as file and import. Otherwise use some other MySQL client for achieve the same. I use HeidiSQL.

Comment: As the MySQL server wont start, this is not going to be much help now is it?